# Jquery AJAX variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This should be really simple but it's after 2am and I'm struggling!

So I have a PHP file that outputs a database query in JSON format.  The plan is then to use Columns (https://github.com/eisenbraun/columns) to format this JSON into a simple table.

The page has a box with a value, when clicking on this value, I want to use AJAX to get the result from my PHP script and display a table.

Currently, I have the table loading at the same time as the page;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var json1 = <?php include($inc.'xx\sp1.php');?>;
  $('#sp1').columns({data:json1});

  var json2 = <?php include($inc.'xx\sp2.php');?>;
  $('#sp2').columns({data:json2});
});
</script>
```

with the links on the value being;

```
<a class='btn btn-secondary' data-toggle="modal" href="#sp1">
<a class='btn btn-secondary' data-toggle="modal" href="#sp2">
```

How can I set the variables (Json1 & Json2) and load the data via an AJAX on click event?  I know it's staring me in the face and it's hugely frustrating!

Comment: First you need to bind a click event on the buttons and define an event handler. Then you need to use the ajax method to call your server. What specifically are you having issues with? Have you read any of the tutorials on click event handlers and ajax calls in jquery? if not start there.

Comment: It looks like the 2 jsons already are defined via PHP echo where `#sp1` and `#sp2` are bootstrap modals. There not enought for anyone to understand what you try to achieve. *«The page has a box with a value, when clicking on this value, I want...»* is unclear.

Comment: Thanks Louys,  What I meant was that I want to PHP file to be included when the button is pressed instead of when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple one to be fair but I'll use alcohol and tiredness as an excuse!

```
$('#hf1djm883j').on('click',function (e){    
    $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url :"includes\\files\\private\\798shwo3ixxd\file6llps.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {        
    $('#mmshh5e').columns({data});  
    }
    }); 
});
```